# Is key mod TableSize a good hash function in this particular case

Tags: hash, hashtable

If a user is designing a hash table and knows that all the keys will be multiples of 4 between 0 and 10,000 and evenly distributed. Is the following hash function good?

```
hash(key) = key mod TableSize
```

where TableSize is some prime number.

My intuition is that this function is highly flawed because only 1/4 of the possible keys actually occur. But when I ran tests  the hash values were about evenly distributed.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Here's the code if someone wants to try it:
`code                 
     #include "stdafx.h"
     #include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 int i = 0;
 int taille = 67;
 int* tab = new int [taille];
 for (i = 0; i < taille; i++)
  tab[i] = 0;

 for (i = 0; i < 404; i = i + 4)
 {
  tab[i%taille]++;
 }

 for (i = 0; i < taille; i++)
  std::cout << tab[i] << std::endl;
 std::cin >> i;
}     `

Answer (score 0):

Good enough if except keys are multiples of 4, they are effectively random. BTW why don't you divide each key by 4 (`>> 2`) before putting into the hash table?